# Python Matrix Solver

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I start with a matrix where the only rule is that the first 3 cells in a row must add up to the 4th cell in that row:

[image]

In keeping to that rule, I want to create a new matrix based on the first where the sum of the first 3 rows in each column should be as close to but not above the 4th number in each column like this:

[image]

I think this is something that sort of can be done in excel using Solver but was looking for a way to do it in Python.  If I have to create this from scratch that's fine but my question is, is there something like this is SciPy or another library so I can avoid reinventing the wheel if possible?

EDIT:
I think the second part of this problem is a little unclear.

```
[[ 2.  2.  2. 6.] -> 1st 3 cells can change but sum must always add up to 6
 [ 4.  4.  4. 12.] -> 1st 3 cells can change but sum must always add up to 12
 [ 6.  6.  6. 18.] -> 1st 3 cells can change but sum must always add up to 18
 [ 8.  16.  12. NA.]] -> This cannot change
```

You always start with a matrix where horizontally the sum of the first 3 cells equal the last cell ie 2,2,2,6.  The difficult part is optimizing each row so that vertically they get as close as possible to adding up to the bottom cell.  In this example, 2,4,6,8 runs vertically with the first three adding up to 12.  The resulting matrix should be optimized so that the first three add up to 8 like this:

```
[[ 1.  3.  2. 6.] 
 [ 3.  5.  4. 12.]
 [ 4.  8.  6. 18.] 
 [ 8.  16.  12. NA.]]
```

This new matrix has all rows still adding up to the last cell ie 1,3,2,6 and also vertically adds up to the last cell ie 1,3,4,8.
Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: try to look for it in pandas?

Comment: You have, in effect, nine variables and six equations.  There should be a three-parameter family of exact solutions.  Or are you only interested in solutions whose values are integers?  Your examples show only integer values, so perhaps that is what you want.

Comment: For example, the least-squares (and non-integer) solution for the 3x3 matrix is `[[ 2/3, 10/3,  2], [8/3, 16/3, 4], [14/3, 22/3, 6]]`

Comment: Every value must be an integer.